# How to reload DFP ads ONLY when that ad is IN VIEW of browser window

Tags: javascript, google-dfp

I had gone through the documentation - https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2694377?hl=en

My requirement is that the DFP ads should only be refreshed when user is viewing THAT ad in browser window. If i had scroll OR that ad slot is not visible to user than dfp ad should not be refreshed.

Comment: Hi @dell, Did you found a way to do this?  I was thinking about marking with a class those slots using ImpressionViewableEvent. Did you found a simpler way?

Comment: As @BeWarned answered ImpressionViewableEvent solve half of the problem. A ImpressionNotViewableEvent is missing though. Did someone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to [ImpressionViewableEvent](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.events.ImpressionViewableEvent).
In the event handler call googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);

An alternate approach is to use the [Waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) library, which allows you to setup event handlers that view when an DOM element enters and leaves the window.